# Azure NodeJS backend get last entity

Tags: node.js, azure-mobile-services

I need to take last item of table on Azure Mobile Services with scheduler script.

Here is my sctipt, which is used to do this:

```
tlmtTable
    .orderByDescending('id')                        
    .where({deviceId: deviceId})                        
    .take(1)                        
    .read({ 
        success: function(results) {
                        console.warn(results);                                            
                    }
           });
```

I don't know where is an error, but it doesn't return anything. Whenever I use it without sorting, I see the row on logs. This version of script returns line, but not the last one:

```
tlmtTable   
    .where({deviceId: deviceId})                        
    .take(1)                        
    .read({ 
        success: function(results) {
                        console.warn(results);                                            
                    }
           });
```

I tried to move ".orderByDescending" to other places of query - it doesn't help. I can't realized which way I can sort result and get the last record. Maybe you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using string or integer IDs? By default, IDs are strings and have GUIDs automatically assigned if not specified. Generated GUIDs will not sort the way that you are expecting. A better solution is to use the __createdAt column for sorting instead of id.

Comment: id - integer. It's an auto-generated field.
`[id]                    INT                IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL`,

Comment: You must have created this table manually using SQL Server Management Studio? Regardless, is there a reason why using the __createdAt column for sorting is not an option? This is the preferred approach.